# How can I provide the $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR to ruby -n -e?

Tags: ruby, command-line, io

I'd like to use Ruby's $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR aka $/ to operate on a tab-separated file.

The input file looks like this (grossly simplified):

```
a   b   c
```

(the values are separated by tabs).

I want to get the following output:

```
a---
b---
c---
```

I can easily achieve this by using `ruby -e` and setting the `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR` alias `$/`:

```
cat bla.txt | ruby -e '$/ = "\t"; ARGF.each {|line| puts line.chop + "---" }'
```

This works, but what I'd really like is this:

```
cat bla.txt | ruby -n -e '$/ = "\t"; puts $_.chop + "---" '
```

However, this prints:

```
a       b       c---
```

Apparently, it doesn't use the provided separator - presumably because it has already read the first line before the separator was set. I tried to provide it as an environment variable:

```
cat bla.txt | $/="\n" ruby -n -e 'puts $_.chop + "---" '
```

but this confuses the shell - it tries to interpret $/ as a command (I also tried escaping the $ with one, two, three or four backslashes, all to no avail).

So how can I combine $/ with ruby -n -e ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-0` option :

```
cat bla.txt | ruby -011 -n -e 'puts $_.chop + "---" '
a---
b---
c---
```

> -0[ octal] Sets default record separator ($/) as an octal. Defaults to \0 if octal not specified.

tabs have an ascii code of 9, which in octal is 11. Hence the `-011`

Comment: had trouble making it work at first because I had `set expandtabs` in my .vimrc file.. just a note :/

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `BEGIN` block, which is processed before Ruby begins looping over the lines:

```
$ echo "foo\tbar\tbaz" | \
>   ruby -n -e 'BEGIN { $/ = "\t" }; puts $_.chop + "---"'
foo---
bar---
baz---
```

Or, more readably:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -n
BEGIN {
  $/ = "\t"
}

puts $_.chop + "---"
```

Then:

```
$ chmod u+x script.rb
$ echo "foo\tbar\tbaz" | ./script.rb
foo---
bar---
baz---
```

If this is more than a one-off script (i.e. other people might use it), it may be worthwhile to make it configurable with an argument or an environment variable, e.g. `$/ = ENV['IFS'] || "\t"`.

Comment: Nice (+1). I accepted the answer by @cozyconemotel because it's more compact and IMHO therefore preferable for one-off scripts.